# VS stops debugging without errors if dataGridView1.DataSource is set

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Basic winform program which runs fine. Add this line `dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet;` and it will finish the Form1 constructor code, go to  `Application.Run(new Form1());` then stop debugging without a single error to suggest the problem.

Any ideas how can I work out what's going on here and fix it?

Comment: Is the offending line in a try/catch block?

Comment: Yes and no. Kind of worked it out now. See answer

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the event handler 'EnterRow' that was causing the issues. Of course it only fired when i set the datasource. Stepping through the code never showed the event of course. 
There was no try catch block around the event code, however i still don't know why VS never threw the exception like it normally does. Do not think it was a VS setting issue as it worked for other errors. Forgot to note the exact issue but it was something to do with reading the wrong type from the database.